# Make POD from class with virtual members

Tags: c++, inheritance, serialization

I have two classes: Parent and Derived. I want to achieve ability to save and read them from/to binary file, or transfer them. Please help with idea or code snippets how do it.

```
class Parent {
public:
    virtual int func1(){ return 1; }
    virtual unsigned func2() = 0;
    std::string asd;
}

class Derived : public Parent {
public:
    unsigned func2(){ return 2; }
    bool boo;
}
```

Save to binary file

```
Parent *obj = new Derived;
write_to_file( obj, sizeof(*obj) );
```

Then read from file

```
read_from_file( obj, sizeof(*obj) );
```

But this method will overwrite pointers to virtual functions. So I need to create POD class without virtuals to save it and to read from file. Right? Create reflected POD class for every Derived seems not good idea.

Comment: The virtual functions are not a problem (in the sense that you can work around that easily), but the `std::string` is a problem. You need to decide how you want to save that. Then write code to serialize and deserialize; google that.

Comment: Can't use boost.serialization ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct answer to this question. You should use serialization. C++ has no native serializers, as Java or C#. But there are a lot of open-source serializers over the internet. For example `boost::serialization`, [`s11n`](http://s11n.net/), and many others.